# newNode Memory Leak/Segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct

I am not sure what I am doing wrong for this. My program appears correct but apparently there is a memory leak in my newNode function according to valgrind. I want to know what I am doing wrong in the newNode function and why it is wrong.

The code is:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "list.h"
typedef struct lnode {
   char *term;
   int count;
   int last;
   struct lnode *next;
}lnode,*lnodePtr;
/**
 * Returns a new linked list node filled in with the given word and line, and
 * sets the count to be 1. Make sure to duplicate the word, as the original word
 * may be modified by the calling function.
 */
 struct lnode *newNode (char* word, int line) {
    lnode *add=malloc(sizeof(lnode));
    add->term=(char *)malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy((add -> term), word);
    add->count=1;
    add->last=line;
    add->next=NULL;
    return add;         
  }
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    lnodePtr head=NULL; 
    char example[1000]="Name";
    char *ex=example;
    lnode *amc=newNode(ex,2);
    return(0);
  }
```

So is the problem with just my main but not my newNode function? I am new to linked lists so you can you please help me write freeNode? I thought freeNode would be similar to my deleteNode (apparently it doesnt fix the memory leak). the code for my deleteNode is:

```
void deleteNode (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
    if(*head == NULL)
        return;

    if((node == *head)&&(((*head) -> next) != NULL)) 
    {
        *head = (*head) -> next;
    }
    else if((node == *head)&&(((*head) -> next) == NULL)) 
    {
        void *p = NULL;
        *head = (lnodePtr)p;
    }
    else
    {
        lnode *temp;
        temp=node;
        node=node->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(node);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add free(amc->term); free(amc); before the return statement in main()? Do you still get the warning?

Comment: Your main doesn't call deleteNode, can you show a version that does?

Answer (score 2):

> ...  there is a memory leak in my newNode function ...

Well, you allocated some memory (with `malloc`) and never released it (with `free`). That's the definition of a memory leak.

Your main should look like this to be leak-free:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  lnodePtr head=NULL; 
  char example[1000]="Name";
  char *ex=example;
  lnode *amc=newNode(ex,2);
  // actual work?
  freeNode(amc);
}
```

Now, do you need help writing `freeNode` as well?

Comment: yes since my deleteNode appears wrong too (sorry i'm inexperienced at linked lists and i'm under a time constraint. would greatly appreciate your help). I also want to know if it is main() that is wrong or my neewNode function?

Comment: I always thought that memory leak is anything to which no body points, isnt it like when program exits, the unfree'd memory will be automatically released ? Why it gets counted in memory leak ?

Comment: It isn't a leak in the context of the OS: you're correct that all your process' memory will be reclaimed by the system. However, valgrind is looking at how memory is managed inside your process, where you've leaked a pointer even though the OS will clean it all up after main exits.